# How to randomly pull rows in a groupby until x value is met, then iterate through multiple columns with different 'x' input for each column/group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nested-loops

How can I group a dataset by the 'year' column and then randomly pull from each group the sum of that matching year column is greater than the input value? I am using groupby to try and avoid pulling in the '0' values when taking a random sample

So if I was to use 2024 as an example. The input is 'input_24' and the value is 11. so randomly pull rows where 'year'=2024 until the sum of that column is grater than or equal to 11.

```
input_23 = 5
input_24 = 11
input_25 = 8

sum_23 = int()
sum_24 = int()
sum_25 = int()

output_rows= []
data = {
        'Year':['2023', '2023', '2023', '2024', '2024', '2024', '2025', '2025', '2025', '2025', '2026'],
        'Name':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9','Item10','Item11'],
        '2022':[3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        '2023':[10,5,6,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        '2024':[0,1,0,9,8,5,3,1,2,1,0],
        '2025':[0,0,0,0,0,0,7,6,11,7,2],
        '2026':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have tried a few different methods but am completely stuck on this. Currently I am trying to use groupby but I dont know how to cycle through each column and get it to use the next 'input_xx' value.

```
grouped = data.groupby(['year'])

for name, group in grouped:
  for i in data.sample(frac=1).iterrows():
        if (sum_23 + i[1]['FY23']) <= input_23:
            sum_23 += i[1]['FY23']
            output_row.append(i[1])
        if output_row['FY23'].sum() >= input_23:
            break
```

but using a loop similar to this I can only get it to pull a specific number of rows from every group including the '0' values, or own column at a time and then I have to duplicate the code for each column.

I also read that I could try a groupby lamda function but have not figured out how that would work.

```
df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Does anyone have an idea or suggestion?

Comment: That is not a valid dataframe, try running the first code snippet.

Comment: whoops, I corrected the example database so it works.

Comment: Are you expecting to end up with a new dataframe for each year?  Or do you want a single dataframe that satisfies all of the minimums?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.  A simple while loop that concats random rows to an output dataframe until the sums meet the requirements for all columns.

```
import pandas as pd

input_23 = 5
input_24 = 11
input_25 = 8

data = {
        'Year':['2023', '2023', '2023', '2024', '2024', '2024', '2025', '2025', '2025', '2025', '2026'],
        'Name':['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9','Item10','Item11'],
        '2022':[3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        '2023':[10,5,6,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        '2024':[0,1,0,9,8,5,3,1,2,1,0],
        '2025':[0,0,0,0,0,0,7,6,11,7,2],
        '2026':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Empty df with the same columns as the main dataframe, which will hold sampled rows
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Continue to concat random samples until totals meet or exceed the minimum for all columns
while out['2023'].sum() <= input_23 and out['2024'].sum() <= input_24 and out['2025'].sum() <= input_25:
    out = pd.concat([df.groupby('Year').sample(1).reset_index(drop=True),out])
```

Comment: Almost! the only difference is I need to know which rows were chosen and see them split out in the new output dataframe.

Comment: I changed the code slightly to group by 'year' and 'name' to get the output but that ended up showing me the full list again.